# How to query SQLite for whether a record exists?

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

In the commented-out line below, PlatypusId is red/not recognized, although it does exist in the corresponding table.

In the multi-line spanning assignment to queryResult, PlatypusId, where, and count are red/unrecognized.

```
    //var queryResult = await conn.Table<PlatypiRequested>().CountAsync().(x => x.PlatypusId.Equals(personId));
    var queryResult = from p in PlatypiRequested
                      where p.PlatypusId.Equals(platypusId)
                      select count;
```

IOW, when I add this:

```
    var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    var queryResult = await conn.Table<PlatypiRequested>().CountAsync().(x => x.
```

...nothing is proffered as a possibility following that "x => x."

What sort of code is necessary to query my SQLite table?

I am using the SQLite-net package/extension, but its documentation (what documentation?) is not overly verbose. Looking through both SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs, I'm none the wiser...

### UPDATE

Okay, Mr. Harvey's answer comment led me to this working code (Count() was not available, just CountAsync()):

```
public async Task<bool> PlatypusAlreadyAdded(string platypusId)
{
    var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(SQLitePath);
    var queryResult = await conn.Table<PlatypiRequested>().Where(x => x.PlatypusId == platypusId).CountAsync();
    return queryResult > 0;
}
```

As Jackie DeShannon (no relation to me, AFAIK) sang, "What the world needs now is a "SQLite/SQLite-net for C# Windows Store apps"" book (or at least a lengthy/informative blog post, containing examples of all the common types of SQL statements (CRUD)).

Comment: I think what you're really looking for is something like `var queryResult = await conn.Table<PeopleRequested>().Where(x => x.someField == someValue).CountAsync();`  Your way is not going to work, since the last `.` operator is expecting a method call, not an opening parenthesis or lambda expression.

Comment: Sounds promising, but this:

            var queryResult = await conn.Table<PlatypiRequested>(x => x.PlatypusId == platypusId).CountAsync(); 

...still does not recognize x.PlatypusId, and I get the err msg, "No overload for method 'Table' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: I edited my comment while you were typing yours. :)  Note that if you are using `await`, you may not need the Async version of Count() (or any other Async functions from SQLite, for that matter), since `await` already modifies the code for you under the covers to make it asynchronous.

Comment: Also note that the `Count()` extension method has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) that takes a condition as a parameter.

Comment: Make it an Answer instead of a comment, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're really looking for is something like

```
var queryResult = await conn.Table<PeopleRequested>()
                            .Where(x => x.someField == someValue)
                            .CountAsync();
```

Your way is not going to work, since the last `.` operator is expecting a method call, not an opening parenthesis or lambda expression.